# how to configure samba to be visible in another subnet

Tags: routing, samba, subnet

I have a subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and in it I have a smbd/nmbd server The samba server is for example: 192.168.1.25 the gateway/router here is 192.168.1.1

in this subnet there is a cascading router 192.168.1.100 that has his own subnet 192.168.2.0/24, in this second subnet there are some windows clients who must access the samba shares at 192.168.1.25

the second router (192.168.1.100) has nat,

and the windows client from (192.168.2.10) can ping  192.168.1.25 but the samba server (192.168.1.25) does not appear in the windows network neighborhood.

how to configure this?

Comment: can you provide more detail on your routing - Does the cascaded router do NAT? Can the clients ping the SAmba server?

Comment: @davidgo I updated the question

Comment: You don’t configure Samba to be visible on the machine, whatever the machine is plugged into, must make the other subnet visible. How you do that depends on your networking equipment.

Comment: Instead of using network neighborhood, you can map it directly by ip address or DNS name or hostname if you can assign that locally.

Comment: @Ramhound Im fairly sure thats only partially correct - I am pretty sure you can go to a SMB address via IP even if you are not on the same network.  Do Im guessing (without a Wi dows box or smb to test), If NAT and firewalling allows it the OP can go to //192.168.1.25/  and browse the network.